# How do I dual boot ubuntu mate and mac OS X 10.5 on a PowerMac G5?

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, powerpc

I would like to try a dual boot configuration on my Mac but I have no idea how to dual boot on a Macintosh. Especially one this old.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1472474)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation) shows how to set a Mac to dual boot with Ubuntu.

From the link:

> BACKUP YOUR DATA
>
> Quick Steps:  Install rEFIt and make sure it is working (you should
>   get a boot chooser on startup) Use Bootcamp or Disk Utility to create
>   a partition at the end of the disc. Don’t worry about what format,
>   just make it the size you want for Ubuntu and your swap partition. If
>   you you are using OS X Lion which comes with Bootcamp 4.0 you will
>   need to use the Disk Utility. Boot Camp 4.0 will only allow you to
>   resize if you provide a Windows 7 installation disk. Boot the Ubuntu
>   desktop CD, and select "Try Ubuntu. Start the partition editor
>   (gparted) under System > Adminstration. Use gparted to delete the
>   partition you just made in OS X. It should be the last partition on
>   the disc and follows after the HFS+ partition (OS X). Deleting it will
>   leave an area called unallocated. This is free space, and exactly what
>   you want. Use gparted to manually partition the space on your drive
>   for Ubuntu. First create a SWAP area of about 1GB. Then the rest of
>   the unallocated area format as EXT4. Apply changes and take note the
>   label of the EXT4 partition such as /dev/sda3.
>
> Start the Ubuntu Installer from the desktop icon. When prompted,
>   choose to manually partition. Select the EXT4 partition and click
>   change. Select to use the space as EXT4 and root (/) as the mount
>   point. You will also want to check the box to format the partition. 
>   Reboot when done with the install, and in the rEFIt menu, choose the
>   partition tool. It will attempt to sync the partition tables on your
>   disk. Then SHUTDOWN the computer (not reboot), and start it again. You
>   should be able to boot to Ubuntu now. If it seems to freeze on the tux
>   logo, completely shutdown again and try one more time.
>
> Installing rEFIt:  INSTALL rEFIt! You don’t HAVE to use it once you
>   get Ubuntu up and running, but until then, INSTALL rEFIt! You will
>   need it after installing to sync partitions, once you have done that
>   and Ubuntu works, then you can uninstall it. You can even burn a rEFIt
>   CD if you prefer. If you do not see the rEFIt boot menu when starting
>   your Mac on the second reboot (It takes two reboots to apear after
>   using the package installer), it is not installed properly!
>
> Partitioning:  The first thing we need to do is repartition your Mac’s
>   hard drive. Of course, we would like to do this non-destructively
>   (without wiping out the partition you have already). With Leopard,
>   this is quite easy as Apple has provided a nifty little tool that will
>   shrink your OSX partition and create a Windows partition in the freed
>   space (which we can convert to Linux partitions later). BootCamp is
>   probably the easiest way to accomplish what you need.
>
> Boot your Mac from the CD:  Put the Ubuntu LiveCD in your Mac and
>   reboot.
>
> When the rEFIt menu comes up You should get the option to boot from
>   the Ubuntu CD. If you do not see this option, try pressing the Option
>   key when your computer starts. On a Mac, the "c" key will instruct the
>   Mac to attempt booting off of a CD/DVD.
>
> On the Ubuntu CD’s boot menu, select your keyboard language, then
>   choose to "Try Ubuntu". This will start a LiveCD Ubuntu session, which
>   makes no changes to your Mac.
>
> Booting into Ubuntu this way takes many minutes, including a
>   minutes-long period where Ubuntu appears to have locked up on the boot
>   menu. Most likely it has not. Just wait! note I had to set the boot
>   option to nomodeset. If you press function f6 at the boot options
>   screen you can choose that option. Note 2: I had to press function f6
>   when I saw a man and keyboard.
>
> Once booted, you have a Ubuntu desktop. Start gparted (partitioning
>   tool) by navigating to System > Adminstration > Partition Editor.
>
> If you previously created an “msdos” style partition used Boot Camp,
>   you should use gparted to delete this partition. It will be located
>   after an EFI partition (hidden in OSX) and an HFS+ partition (HFS+ is
>   OS X's filesystem). Deleting the new partition leaves “free space” on
>   the disk for the Ubuntu install. Use gparted to manually partition the
>   space on your drive for Ubuntu. First create a SWAP area of about 1GB.
>   Then the rest of the unallocated area format as EXT4. Apply changes
>   and take note the label of the EXT4 partition such as /dev/sda3.
>
> Fix the Partition Tables:  There is a bug in the installer that causes
>   a problem on Macs. FIXME: Describe problem? It can be fixed with
>   rEFIt.
>
> Reboot to the rEFIt menu and select the “partition tool”. rEFIt will
>   ask if you would like to sync your partition tables. Say Yes and let
>   it do it’s magic. (If you don't have an English keyboard, note that
>   the keys "Z" and "Y" are swapped in the partition tool.) If you see
>   the error "GPT partition of type 'Unknown' found, will not touch this
>   disk" instead of the 'yes' prompt, follow the instructions in comment
>   6 of this thread and make sure to install gptsync_0.13-10 or higher.
>
> rEFIt may not offer to sync your partition tables, but just show the
>   error and leave no option but a return to the main menu. For
>   suggestions on other ways to fix the table, see the discussion at
>   Ubuntu on MacBookPro - difficulties w partition tables.
>
> if you have errors such as "GPT partition of type 'Unknown' found,
>   will not touch this disk." or "analysis inconclusive" as explained in
>   this thread, then you have to use gdisk to rebuild the partition
>   table. This is best explained in this post - boot a live Ubuntu CD
>   (the instructions say this is also possible from an OS X terminal),
>   install and run the gdisk tool as the instructions say.
>
> After it is done, SHUTDOWN your Mac (not reboot) and startup again.
>   You should now be able to boot into Ubuntu. If you select the Linux
>   Icon in rEFIt, and it freezes on the grey Tux logo, shutdown again and
>   try one more time.

Comment: From the Help Center, "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: Ok, link changed.

Comment: What you really need to do is included the key points from the linked article in your answer. The answer should never be just a link to an external site.

Comment: I will try this, are you sure it will rEFI will work with a powerpc mac?

Comment: I have never tried, I have just tried dual boot with mac and windows using boot camp